# Farther vs. Further (in the context)

Tags: word-choice

I've got this [explanation](http://www.softschools.com/quizzes/vocabulary/farther_vs_further/quiz9170.html), about using Farther vs. Further:

> The words farther and further both refer to a greater distance. However, farther is typically used when the distance is physical, and further is used when the distance is abstract or metaphorical. Further may be used to mean 'more' or 'to a greater degree.'

In following the explanation, there is a quiz, which gives back the right word to use (farther OR further). Please see below.

A. The ***further*** I have to drive, the more my back bothers me.

B. How much ***farther*** to Mimi's house?

I want to ask, if the other option work as well, in both sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Farther* does tend to be used for measurements of distance. The tip I was given to remember this is that it has "far" in it.

*Further* does not have to relate to physical distance. You can have "further reading", or "further education", for example.

Both your examples seem correct. The second is clearly about distance because it asks "how far". However, the first example of "*driving further*" could mean *continuing* to drive and arguably relates to the *time* spent driving. When you consider that the sentence cites the amount of driving as the cause of back pain this makes sense, as the time spent in a sitting position would aggravate this, not the number of miles travelled. You could travel 60 miles in one hour at 60mph or just 30 miles in the same amount of time at 30mph.